# bigquery-public-dataのnewyork.citibikedataを使用したサブクエリを作成する課題で出る、BigqueryのSQLエラーの解決法が分からない。

Tags: google-bigquery

Bigqueryで下記SQLを記述時に以下のエラーになります

```
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [16:56]
```

どこを直せばいいのかが分からない状態です。
原因と対策をお教えいただけますでしょうか。

記述は以下の通りです。

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  name,
  num_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station,
  FROM
   (
    SELECT
      ct.start_station_id,
      COUNT(*) number_of_rides
    FROM  `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips` AS ct
      GROUP BY
        start_station_id
    )
    AS station_num_trips
    INNER JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations` ON station_id = start_station_id
  ORDER BY
    number_of_rides DESC
```

error

```
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [16:56]
```